# Webservice interface to UI Automation

Tags: web-services, ui-automation

I want to provide a WS interface to Web UI Automation. For example , I call a  webservice passing what workflow to test and this webservice will kick start webui automation (selenium) on remote machine and gives back the result.Is it possible ? Can i develop a webapp with selenium in it and expose a webservice?

Comment: I was thinking about wiritng HtmlUnit test as WebApp and deploying on server,with WS interface. But my interest is to run browser driven tests,

Comment: Great. Do you have a specific UI automation platform in mind, or are you just asking in general?

Comment: WatIN , because rest of the E2E automatuion is develiped in .NET and I want to have some mechanism to hook this with E2E. I am planning to try Jekins ,i am open to other ideas as well.

Comment: Quick thought to look into Microsoft Test Manager, which can record and play back manual tests, and Visual Studio Ultimate which can take those recordings and produce automated tests from them.

Comment: I doubt I can get Test Manager or Ultimate. I have to convince lots of people to get the license.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest checking out a CI tool like Jenkins and using that to control your Selenium tests:

http://jenkins-ci.org/

The scenario you describe is very close to how I use Jenkins - for Selenium testing, I have two machines: One with the Jenkins server installed, and another Windows machine that simply exists to run automated tests.

(Note that you can also make the Jenkins server run Selenium tests on itself, if you want a one-machine setup.)

Several times a day my Jenkins server connects to the Windows machine and launches a Selenium test suite, then emails me the console output of my Selenium process.

Using a CI tool for this type of testing is very flexible, as you can configure a Jenkins job to run at specific times of day, automatically when changes are made to specific files in your source control system, or launch a test job manually in the Jenkins web app.

More importantly (given your needs), Jenkins also has a remote access API, so you can script the launch of test jobs if you like:

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Remote+access+API

As documented there, you can launch a job with a simple HTTP GET request to the Jenkins server.  Very cool.

Comment: Wow, this exactly solves my problem . Thanks for your suggestion.I will try this out.

Comment: Cheers, hope it helps.  I really love Jenkins.